# Convert external USB to FAT32 to NTFS, error 490@01010004

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, fat32

I'm trying to run:

```
convert I: /fs:NTFS /X
```

on my portable USB hard disk (500GB Freecom XXS), which is currently FAT32 (to enable support for files larger than 4GB, mainly) but it keeps erroring out with:

> "Unexpected failure. Error code: 490@01010004"

from VDS Basic Manager, event ID 1, in the system events log.

I've looked on Google, tried rebooting, running the same in Safe Mode with Command Prompt, both with and without the `/X` switch, all produce nothing.

Environment:

- Windows 7 Ultimate N 64-bit
- UAC disabled (so Command Prompt runs as an administrator by default).
- Daemon Tools is installed; I've also installed the updated SPTD driver from [here](http://www.duplexsecure.com/downloads/) for 64-bit as another forum mentioned that that may be the issue. Still nothing.

Any ideas how to get past this error?

Comment: I'm going to move all the files off the disk, format to NTFS, then move them back, cause this is causing way too much ballache. However I'd still be curious to know the answer to this.

Comment: Uninstall the sptd driver, then try conversion

Comment: Add /V to see what gets done and what doesn't.